# will installing several IDEs cause problems

Tags: eclipse, ide, intellij-idea, aptana

I'm trying to evaluate a number of IDEs like Eclipse, intelliJ, Aptana, etc. to see which one suits my needs. My question is should I expect any problems from installing several IDEs on the same computer? I know that some IDEs are based on others (Aptana is eclipse-based) but intelliJ isn't), so would there be any problem installing both Aptana and Eclipse for example? Do you have more than a single IDE running together without problems? which ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had both Eclipse and Aptana installed on the same machine with no problems.  I've got Eclipse and NetBeans on this machine now, and I know that they don't interfere with one another in the slightest.

I've also had different versions of the same IDE (NetBeans) installed on one machine, with the different versions installed in different directories, and even that didn't cause any problems.  You can even point them at the same project folders if you want.

Comment: +1 though I'd be careful with pointing them at the same project folders (this goes for different versions of Eclipse; I haven't used NetBeans in a long while). They **will** overwrite their own files (.project / .classpath / preferences).

Comment: @ChssPly76: That's a good point.  Some IDEs may use project files in a common area, while some keep them separated.  It's as good idea to find out which your preferred IDE does.

Answer (score 3):

I really doubt it's going to cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be installing many version of the same basic IDE (Eclipse and Aptana for example) I would try to keep them both at the newest version of each just in case libraries are being shared.

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 2):

You can install as many IDE as you need it won't create any particular issue.

The only possible issue if you are using some network debugging(php debuggine for instance) they can battle for accessing the TCP port but that's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

My school computers have Eclipse, Netbeans, Anjuta, Kdevelop and several other obscure IDEs and they work fine.

Comment: I know this was like 11 years ago, but may I ask why they had so many?